# How to find out what files were changed in a git branch (not the difference between two branches)

Tags: git, git-branch, git-diff

I have a branch named `feature_219` which was created from `master` a little while ago. Since the diversion, there were a number of files changed on both the branches.

Now I am trying to figure out what files where changed while working on the `feature_219` branch only.

After doing some research I found out that `git diff --name-only master feature_219` might help but it turned out that this commands tells about all files that are different in both the branches. I tried to look for some option with this command but nothing worked for me.

Is there any way to list only those files that were changed in `feature_219` branch?

Comment: Your question is unclear. "Different" compared to what? To the merge base of `feature_219` and `master`? Be more specific. Whenever you use the word "different", specify also what you're comparing to.

Comment: *Is there any way to list only those files that were changed in feature_219 branch?* Changed with respect to what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `git merge-base` to find a common ancestor of two branches, then get the diff.

```
git diff --name-only feature_219 $(git merge-base master feature_219)
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the [git diff documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

```
git diff --name-only master...feature_219
```

should do the trick. Notice the three dots.
If you're currently on branch `feature_219`

```
git diff --name-only master...
```

suffices. The order of the two branches is very important. Interchanging the two branches in the first call will give you all changes in the `master` branch since you started the `feature_219` branch.

The command `git diff A...B` should be interpreted as "give me all changes which happen in the commits when going from `A` to `B`". If `A` is not a parent of `B` (as in this case) the common ancestor will be used to answer this question.